# Прямая ссылка на страницу внутри

Tags: php, javascript, framework7

Подскажите кто сталкивался, пишу веб-приложение с помощью framework7, так вот стартовая страница которая загружает все скрипты условно index.html, а как в таких проектах давать прямую ссылку внутрь приложения?

(в принципе актуально для любых одностраничных веб-приложений)

Например:
site.com/catalog/tehnica/simens

Физически такой структуры нет, и работает по сути одна страница index.html

Нужно делать переадресацию на главную страницу и считывать URL строку? (с последующей обработкой и показом нужного контента) или как?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Именно с framework7 я не работал но думаю есть два решения.
1. Cовсем недавно я отвечал на подобный вопрос, может чем то поможет [Ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/782354/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82/782523#782523). Но скорее всего это не совсем верно в Вашем случае.
2. Так же несложными движениями [routes в framework7](https://framework7.io/docs/routes.html), скорее всего именно это Вам и нужно.